# Requesting multiple users from single ticket | mysql many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization

I want to create a list of all the tickets that a specific customer submitted into the application in addition information from a developer that is going to solve the ticket. In the application a user can be a customer or a developer.

A ticket can have multiple users (for example a customer and developer) and a user can have multiple tickets (a customer can submit multiple tickets and a developer can receive multiple tickets). That's why I added a many to many relation between tickets and users.

I designed the database like this:

```
tickets     tickets_users   users         groups
ticket_id   fk_ticket_id    user_id       group_id
            fk_user_id      fk_group_id   group_type
```

Is there a way to collect information about ticket(s) for a specific customer with the developer(s) in a single query. If not, have you a better suggestion changing my database?

I want to get a list something like this for the customer Andrew:

```
ticket status     ticket priority  developer
```

---

```
Identify ticket    high             John
Identify ticket    low              Austin
etc                etc              etc
```

So far I have made this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets t 
  JOIN tickets_users tu ON tu.fk_ticket_id=t.ticket_id
  JOIN users u ON u.user_id=tu.fk_user_id
  JOIN groups g ON g.group_id=u.fk_group_id
  WHERE user_id = $customerId
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: And where does the developer field come from?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query itself. I want to create a list of all the tickets that a specific customer submitted into the application in addition information from a developer that is going to solve the ticket. And I don't know how I'm going to do this with a many to many relation.

Comment: A developer user is defined in the table groups, group_type for example 1 is customer and 2 is developer.

Comment: @Shadow that is my question. I want to have a developer field but I don't know where to define that in the database

Comment: You could have put this into the question. It was absolutely unclear what you wanted.

Comment: @Shadow What do you not understand about my question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join users and groups twice to a ticket, once to get the person, who raised a ticket, once to get the developer, who will deal with it. However, in this scenario, the developers cannot raise a ticket.

```
SELECT t.ticket_status, t.ticket_priority, u2.user_name as developer FROM tickets t 
  JOIN tickets_users tu ON tu.fk_ticket_id=t.ticket_id
  INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.user_id=tu.fk_user_id AND u1.user_id = $customerId
  INNER JOIN groups g1 ON g1.group_id=u1.fk_group_id AND g1.group_type=1
  INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id=tu.fk_user_id
  INNER JOIN groups g2 ON g2.group_id=u2.fk_group_id AND g2.group_type=2
```

If a ticket does not have a developer assigned, then it would not show up in the report. You need to change u2 and g2 joins to left joins, if you want to include these in the resultset.

However, if you know that a ticket has a single raiser and a single developer, who works on it, then you should include 2 fields referencing the users table in the ticket table, no need for a connection table.

Comment: _"However, if you know that a ticket has a single raiser and a single developer, who works on it, then you should include 2 fields referencing the users table in the ticket table, no need for a connection table."_

**I know that a single ticket has only 1 customer and 1 developer so you mean I can add 2 fields into the tickets table with ticket_developer and ticket_customer and leave there the users id in it?**

Comment: Yes. Although, I would consider escalation procedures and their impact on your data structure as well.